# Contacting someone unannounced via chat

Tags: discussion, chat, notifications, super-ping

Is there some way to contact another user by using their name in chat, so that they get notified?

It seems that when discussion starts in a comment thread, it is easiest, instead of migrating the entire set of comments, just to start talking about the topic in chat. But to get someone to go there, one continues in the comment thread to say 'hey, let's go to chat'.

Using `@ThePersonsNameYouWantToChatWith` in chat doesn't seem to give them a notification; how can one notify them that you are said something in chat to them?

Answer (score 12):

> Using '@ThePersonsNameYouWantToChatWith' in chat doesn't seem to give them a notification; how can one notify them that you are said something in chat to them?

You can't, unless the person's been recently active in the room you're currently in. Only moderators can use a "super-ping" feature to invite people to chat, even if they haven't visited it before.

What you can always do is [create a new chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new), and drop the user a comment to join you. It's what I did a couple of times already, and it's not much of an overhead.

Comment: Might want to mention that you can *invite* users into a room (different from @-pinging) if they already have a chat account.

Comment: @Shog9 Feel free to add how that works, because I personally haven't found this feature yet, although it's advertised in the chat FAQ.

Comment: @slhck It's in the menu when you click on a user

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I see. Doesn't seem to work for [all users listed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users) though.

Comment: I would, but I have no idea how it works @slhck ;-P

Comment: Hmm yeah, the FAQ mention of inviting is totally wrong; I'll fix that. You can invite either directly from the user's profile page or, as @MichaelMrozek said, from the popup that appears when you click on the user in the live chat. Note that you can only invite to a room that you're already in.